# Forcing a sentence containing quotes to be a String - Java

Tags: java, sql, string

How do i force a sentence in Java to be a string?

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms("3")";
```

Bedrooms row is a varchar which id like to insert the 3 as a string but i keep getting SQL error

Whats the correct statement? Thanks

Comment: You need the escape sequence \\

Comment: Use single quotes around `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PreparedStatement` and don't forget proper SQL (you're missing `VALUES` for your `INSERT` statement)

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(addBedrooms);
ps.setString(1, "3");
int rowCount = ps.executeUpdate();
```

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for an in-depth description.

Answer (score 1):

Escape:

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms(\\\"3\\\")";
```

One `\` for javac, the next for your DBMS itself. The third for the quote mark.

Or, use:

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms('3')";
```

Comment: I think you mean String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms(\\\"3\\\")"; The first will not compile

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement, even as a Java string, must enclose SQL strings with single-quotes, not double-quotes:

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms('3')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes or escape the double quotes.

Single quotes

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms('3')";
```

Double quotes:

```
String addBedrooms = "INSERT INTO Property.Bedrooms(\\\"3\\\")";
```

NOTE: `\\` to create an escape character for the dbms and `\"` escapes the double quote for java